# Problem using INNER JOIN on MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, join

Im new in this community and have a question.

I'm working with this query:

```
select State_a, Confirmed_a, State_b, Confirmed_b 
from vars.jun20 
join vars.jan21 on jun20.Region=jan21.Region;
```

Where `jun20` and `jan21` match in `States` column and different confirmed values, but when I run the query I get this:

[image]

My objective is to get something like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zohIQ.png)

What I want is to get all the States_a and Confirmed_b along with States_b and Confirmed_b well differentiated to calculete then a difference between Confirmed_b - Confirmed_a, I don't really know how to solve it. Any help would be great.

Comment: If they match in the States column, why are you using `Region` in the `ON` condition?

Comment: I want a separate list that is group by State

Comment: Please show sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Can you see the image?

Comment: add vars.jun20.region & vars.jun21.region to your query results (the select), you'll see they match on those values.  as said earlier, region is not equal to state. so your have the wrong expectations.

Comment: Yes, I can. that shows the result you're getting, it doesn't show the input data, and doesn't show the result you want.

Comment: On stackoverflow.com, it is better to write text, than to post images. Especially if those images only show text (see: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) )

Comment: You're getting a full cross product of all the rows in the same region.

Comment: But how? I get the same result with te repeated States_b

Comment: Please re-read all the comments from Barmar, and then think about what "jun20.Region=jan21.Region" in your SQL statement is doing.....